# Xamarin Component restore overrides CSPROJ package reference (Auth0 & Newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, json.net, auth0

I have a solution w/ two projects: `"Project A"` and `"Project B"`.

- `"Project B"` references:

  - Newtonsoft.Json (v10.0.3 from nuget (so under ../packages))
- `"Project A"` references:

  - `"Project B"`
  - `"Auth0"` (from Component Store (so under ../components)
- `"Auth0"` references:

  - `"Newtonsoft.Json"` (v6)

Right now when I build the app, `"Project A"` fails to compile because it needs v10 not v6 of Newtonsoft.Json. The Auth0 component's dependency is overwriting the v10 that I actually want to use.

I want `"Project A"` to build with v10 and I don't care if `"Project B"` uses v10 or v6. How can I force `"Project A"` to use v10 instead of the Auth0 component of sub-project `"Project B"` from overwriting the specific version of Newtonsoft.Json that I want?

### Workaround (not an answer)

A workaround I've found is:

1. remove the `Newtonsoft.Json` referenced from the IDE under

> `<Solution>/Project A/References/From Packages`

2. remove the `Newtonsoft.Json` referenced from the IDE under

> `<Solution>/Project A/Packages`

3. re-add the `Newtonsoft.Json` referenced from the IDE under

> `<Solution>/Project A/Packages`

Then the build works. This has to be done every time I do a `git clean -dfx` (which removed the /components and /packages directories) and restart Xamarin Studio.

Comment: what, specifically, is your question? =)

Comment: Rather than including an answer inside your question, could you please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so the rest of us can know at a glance that an answer exists?

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I've updated my question. Hopefully it makes more sense :)